# On changing script attribute value dynamically, reloads html with appending new script replacing previous one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change its script in the head section of the HTML dynamically on clicking the button and want to reload the page with a new script(with its new values) replacing previous one with JavaScript.

```js
/* To change the root api */
function passRoot(data) {
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  var newScript = document.createElement("script");
  newScript.id = "someID";
  newScript.setAttribute("data-root", parsedData["data-root"]);
  newScript.setAttribute("api-root", parsedData["api-root"]);
  newScript.setAttribute("src", parsedData["src"]);
  document.head.appendChild(newScript);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <script id="someID" api-root="some-api-value" data-root="some-data-value" src="some-src-value"></script>
</head>

<body>
  script change:
  <textarea style="font-size: 9px; width: 90%; height: 30%" id="passroot">
{"api-root": "enter new value", "data-root": "enter new value", "src":"some-new-src-value"}</textarea
        >
        <div>
          <button onclick="passRoot(document.querySelector('#passroot').value)">
            Submit to change script
          </button>
        </div>
**************html-starts***********************************<br>
 stuff I manage with bundle, here I want to load new bundle after providing new url in the src of script tag
</body>
</html>
```

Please open `view frame source` in the code snippet to see the script tag.

[image]

**Please help!**

Comment: The problem is that when you reload the page, the first script will be loaded again. So for now i don't know how you will deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to change the script tag. If you want to load your js on some event. Let's say button click. Please go for Dynamic import that will run your script file.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page the script will be removed. So you need to use `localStorage` to keep current script attribute:

```
let scriptData = localStorage.getItem('script');
if (scriptData)
    craeteScript(scriptData);

function craeteScript(data) {
    localStorage.setItem('script', data)
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.id = "someID";
    newScript.setAttribute("data-root", parsedData["data-root"]);
    newScript.setAttribute("api-root", parsedData["api-root"]);
    newScript.setAttribute("src", parsedData["src"]);
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
}

function passRoot(data) {
    craeteScript(data);
    window.location.reload();
}
```